# Any reason why an organisation should NOT register for an event?

Tags: civievent, drupal, webform-civicrm

I have a draft webform set up to allow an organisation to register for an event (for an exhibition stand booking).
Is there any reason NOT to do this?

Civi 5.11, Drupal 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason why an Organisation contact can't register for Event. ATM its not supported through CiviCRM online registration form however you can use Drupal Webform to register Organisation for event.

HTH

Pradeep

Answer (score 3):

Here’s a reason:

There will be a person/(Individual) that will show up at the Event to staff a booth, to join an opening reception. The invoice will typically also go to an Individual Attn of: working for a company.

So best way to handle this is to add two Contacts to your webform: one of Contact Type Individual and one of Contact Type Organization. You can connected the two with Current Employer field for the Individual.

Then you can have the information you need to print a Name Tag, send a Thank you letter etc.

Comment: Thanks Karin - I've set up the webform with a 'contact person' as the second contact, and we have a separate form for registering the staff who will staff the booth. But you identified a problem that I hadn't thought of  i.e. the email address of the person to receive the invoice.

Comment: I can make the email address to receive the invoice that of the contact person.

The reason we have the Org as the 'owner' of the registration is that people change companies and it's then more difficult to track companies' exhibition history.

Am I missing an easy way to create an exhibiting history record for the company?